# Why xsl:result-document fails inside <xsl:attribute> instruction?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm using Saxon-EE 9.3.0.4 for xsl transformations and found that when  `<xsl:result-document>`  is used inside `<xsl:attribute>` (as well as `<xsl:namespace>`, `<xsl:processing-instruction>`) instruction, processor 
raises [XTDE1480](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#err-XTDE1480) error - *Cannot switch to a final result destination while writing a temporary tree*

```
<xsl:attribute name="a">
    <xsl:result-document href="result.xml" > - error here
        test
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:attribute>
```

According to [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document) (Appendix D) permitted parents for `<xsl:result-document>` are:

- any XSLT element whose content model is sequence constructor
- any literal result element

Is this is bug in Saxon or limitations for `<xsl:result-document>` usage, which are not defined in specification?

**Update:**
I believe that this is not a good idea to use `<xsl:result-document>` inside `<xsl:attribute>`, but why error happens?

Thanks

Comment: @Vincent Biragnet provides a good explanation. Besides this, it is meaningless to use `<xsl:result-document>` to produce an attribute's value. As per spec the content of the `<xsl:attribute>` must be a sequence-constructor. On the other side, `<xsl:result-document>` isn't a sequence constructor. Therefore, regardless of the error message, putting an `<xsl:result-document>` inside an  `<xsl:attribute>` is wrong. `xsl:result-document` produces a final-result-tree. As per spec: [Definition: A final result tree forms part of the final output. Once created is not accessible within the stylesheet.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the spec, you can read :

> The instructions in the initial template are evaluated in final output
>   state. An instruction is evaluated in the same output state as its
>   calling instruction, except that xsl:variable, xsl:param,
>   xsl:with-param, xsl:attribute, xsl:comment,
>   xsl:processing-instruction, xsl:namespace, xsl:value-of, xsl:function,
>   xsl:key, xsl:sort, and xsl:message always evaluate the instructions in
>   their contained sequence constructor in temporary output state.

The xsl:result-document write in a final tree result, and given the rule above, I understand that it is an error to try writting in a final tree result when inside the following elements

> xsl:variable, xsl:param, xsl:with-param, xsl:attribute, xsl:comment, xsl:processing-instruction, xsl:namespace, xsl:value-of, xsl:function, xsl:key, xsl:sort, and xsl:message

Comment: Yes, *result-document* is not a sequence constructor (as all other instructions), but can be inside of any instruction, which content is sequence-constructor. [Definition: A sequence constructor is a sequence of zero or more sibling nodes in the stylesheet that can be evaluated to return a sequence of nodes and atomic values. The way that the resulting sequence is used depends on the containing instruction.]

Comment: Right, I missed the point and I rewrite my answer after your comment.

Comment: To make it clear that the behaviour is not Saxon specific, I tried a sample with XQSharp and AltovaXML and both give similar error messages("XTDE1480: Cannot create result document with URI 'result.xml' when in the temporary output state.", "XTDE1480: Unexpected [xsl:]result-document instruction used in temporary output state at xsl:result-document").

Comment: @Martin Honnen - yes, and it is completely according specification

Answer (score 1):

Update in 2018: note that the XSLT 3.0 specification relaxes the restrictions. Instructions such as `xsl:attribute` and `xsl:comment` no longer set temporary output state. Recent Saxon versions (certainly 9.8) implement the revised rules.